# Printing on HP officejet 6700

Tags: printing

I have HP officejet 6700 printer.  I have been able to print some documents; but now, I could not print again.  When I try to print, it looks like the printer stored the document to be printed into memory. After a while, even when the printer is on & off, when I wanted to print another document, the previous document will print and stop. I am not sure how long it will take to respond to the next print instruction. Right now, printing is at a stand_still.  Can I get help please ?? I have documents on my system that I must print out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help you. I recently bought the same printer, and got it to work. First, put the DVD in the computer. Then, go here:[image: Setup.exe]

Next, right click and go to the Windows Emulator screen. Then, after this, select Go Online instead of running it from the DVD. [image: Go Online]

If you don't have an account already, register. [image: register]

Then after you have done this, log in:[image: log in]

Then click add printer.[image: Add Printer]

I got an error message at the very end but the printer works fine, I hope this helps.